# Reducing the order of an ode: on what space is the new dependent variable defined?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

When we reduce the order of an o.d.e. by making a substitution of the form $y = \dot{x}$, how do we decide to what space $y$ belongs to? Case in point: consider

$$\ddot{x}  = \sin x, \quad x \in \mathbb{S}$$

Introducing $\dot{x}=y$, the above becomes the system

$$\dot{y} = \sin x, \quad \dot{x}=y$$

Question: is $y \in \mathbb{S}$ or $y \in \mathbb{R}$?

Since the above 2nd order ode may physically represent the pendulum, we can say the orbits are on a cylinder $\mathbb{S} \times \mathbb{R}$ and thus $y \in \mathbb{R}$; however if we study the system without any reference to physics, then how do we decide on what space $y$ is defined?

Comment: Fun fact: until now, neither the author of the question nor the author of the accepted answer saw fit to *vote* on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is considered to be an element of a manifold $M$ (for example, the circle $S^1$), then an orbit $x(t)$ is a path on $M$ parametrised by the one-dimensional time variable $t \in \mathbb{R}$. For such a situation, you want to understand what $\dot{x}(t) = \frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t}(t)$ means, and in particular, in what space it should be defined.

This turns out to be the *tangent space* of the manifold $M$ at the point $x$, denoted by $T_x M$. So, for any time $t$, the velocity of $x(t)$ at that time, denoted by $\dot{x}(t)$, is an element of $T_{x(t)}M$. For the circle $S^1$, the tangent space at any point on $S^1$ is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{R}$. This is due to the definition of the tangent space, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_as_velocities_of_curves). Such a tangent space is a vector space, so any scalar multiple of a vector is also in that space. In other words, there is no a priori bound on the velocities. This is only natural, as the magnitude of velocities should be imposed by the *dynamical system*, and not by the *underlying phase space*. For example, take the ODE $\ddot{x} = \omega^2 x$, with $x \in S^1$. Written as a system, the associated phase space is $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$, so this ODE lives on the same phase space as your system. However, the velocities have maximal magnitude $\omega$, which I can choose to be as large as I want, whereas the maximal velocity of orbits of your ODE is $|\dot{x}| = 1$.